# How to write to two different places with the same buffer? (C-System call)

Tags: c, io, buffer, system-calls, tee

I'm supposed to be implementing the Unix 'tee' command with the option of the '-a' flag which will append the input to the EOF instead of overwriting it. The catch is I can only use C System calls for I/O. I've so far been able to implement everything except multiple outputs.

In my while loop I have two different lines, one which writes to a file, and the other which writes to stdout. If I comment one out, or put one before the other, that works, but keeping both in doesn't. Only the write function I call first will work. I'm assuming because it empties the buffer if I understand correctly.

How can I write out whatever I input to stdin, to both stdout and a file?

```
#include "csapp.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   int aflag = 0;
   int n_char = 0;
   int c,fd;
   char *path;
   char buf;

   opterr = 0;

   // getopt is looking for flags with dashes
   while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "a")) != -1)
      switch (c)
      {
         // assign the aflag value to 1, so we know that arg was applied
         case 'a':
            aflag = 1;
            break;
         case '?':
            if (isprint (optopt))
               fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option \\x%x'.\n",optopt);
            return 1;
         default:
            abort();
      }

   // if the -a flag was provided, we must append, if not overwrite the file
   // by default if the file exists.
   if(aflag == 1) {
      path = argv[2];
      fd = open(path,O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,0);
   } else {
      path = argv[1];
      fd = open(path,O_WRONLY,0);
   }

   // While not EOF, right to stdout and file
   while((n_char=read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf,1)) != 0)
      n_char=write(fd, &buf, 1);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO,&buf,1);
   close(fd);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `{}` in your while loop and put both `write` in it. Without `{}` the `while` loop is only executing the first `write`.

Comment: Thank you my friend, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop does not have `{}`. So, it is considering only first statement, after it, in loop body:

```
   while((n_char=read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf,1)) != 0)
      n_char=write(fd, &buf, 1);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO,&buf,1);  <===== this statement is out of loop body
```

Add `{}` for the block of statements in loop body:

```
   while((n_char=read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf,1)) != 0) {
      n_char=write(fd, &buf, 1);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO,&buf,1);
   }
```

---

**Additional**:

As a part of good programming practice, you should also check the return value of system call('s), like `write()`, using in your program and make sure to do proper error handling.

[write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html):

> On error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use code blocks? I see it a lot in my textbook, which is why I copied that schema. When I code in Java I always use them. Just curious from a syntax perspective.

Comment: I don't know which textbook you are referring to. Without curly braces, only the first statement following the loop definition is considered to belong to the loop body, that means the loop only has a single statement. With curly braces, statement(s) between `{` and `}` are considered as loop body and it can be a single statement or more than one statement.

Comment: Understood, is it best practice to always put curly braces? I guess that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, it is good programming practice to have curly braces. It makes code easier to read.